# Vue/Jasmine: grabbing an element without using a ref

Tags: vue.js, jasmine, karma-jasmine, vue-test-utils

```
<div :class="$style.dateOf" v-if="hasName">
  test
</div>
```

I am trying to grab an element to test in Jasmine but each time I've done it prior, I grabbed by a ref:

```
  await this.wrapper.setProps({ hasName: true });

  await this.wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

  const container = this.vm.$refs.containerMain as Vue;
```

I don't want to arbitrarily add refs just for testing purposes.  Is there another way
to grab the element in the `vm` without using a ref?

Answer (score 0):

Template refs are used in Vue application to restrict from uncontrolled direct access to DOM that leads to poor quality code. There's no such restriction for tests.

Vue Test utils already has everything to access DOM elements:

```
wrapper.find('div');
```

It makes sense to have element attributes that allow for unique selectors for testing purposes, conventionally `data-testid`.